# How to display product subcategories into my custom post type single page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have created WC product categories and subcategories like: 
Gear (main category) -> Masks (subcategory) -> Full face masks (subcategory's subcategory) ... so on...

When I use `$variations = get_the_terms( the_ID() , 'product_cat' );` on single-{custom-post-type}.php page, I am getting all categories and subcategories. But I want to show only

**Full face masks (subcategory's subcategory)**

How can I do that any idea or solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`wp_list_pluck`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) to return an array in the form of `array(term_id => parent, ...)`, you can do the following (explanation is given in the comments):

```
$variations = get_the_terms( the_ID() , 'product_cat' );
if(is_array($variations)) { //make sure terms were returned
    $parents = wp_list_pluck( $variations, 'parent', 'term_id' );
    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        if($variation->parent && $parents[$variation->parent] && !$parents[$parents[$variation->parent]]) { //if parent's parent has no parent (parent==0) i.e. a top level term (0 evaluates to false when treated as a boolean)
            //display term
        }
    }
}
```